# Combine multiple points to polygons by property

Tags: geojson, cesium, turf

I'm working on a website with a Cesium map, and I'm using turf.js for geo calculations.
I need to find a way to merge a large set of points on the map (with a fixed distance between them) to polygons, by a certain property.

For example, here is a set of points, with two different properties (marked red and orange):
[image]

And the desired output should be something like this:
[image]

The way I tried to approach this is by transforming each point into a square, and then use turf's union on all squares that have the same property. This produced the second image above.
The problem with this solution is that I'm getting a large number of points (can be around 100K) and performing the union on them can sometimes take a very long time (up to 2 minutes), and I need to find a more performance efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevent existing code, otherwise question is most likely to be closed as not compliant with the GIS SE site policy.

Comment: I'm looking for an algorithmic answer, so suppling my code here isn't relevant. I explained the algorithm I'm currently using, explained why it's currently not working for me, and I'm asking for a different approach or solution to the problem.

Comment: That's your opinion, I beg to differ.

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be rather simple. I used the concave algorithm on all points that have the same property (in my case I used [turf.concave](http://turfjs.org/docs/#concave)), and it returned the desired polygons.